# Does knot Floer homology detect knot genus in rational homology spheres?

Tags: reference-request, knot-theory, 3-manifolds, heegaard-floer-homology

My question is the following:

> Does knot Floer homology detect the genus of null-homologous knot in rational homology spheres?

If the answer is yes, I would like to have a reference for the statement of the result and the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link Floer homology detects the Thurston norm, see [this paper](http://msp.org/gt/2009/13-5/gt-v13-n5-p09-s.pdf) by Yi Ni.

**EDIT**: There are some [lecture notes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1411.4540) that Robert Lipshitz just put up on the arXiv, where he discusses the problem you're interested in. I haven't had time to look carefully into them, but he's usually very careful and clear in what he writes.